# How to import react-document-title in app.js - React JS?

Tags: c#, reactjs.net

I am trying to use REACT JS in MVC 4.x Framework. I am able to set the header tag using REACT. However, I am unable to set the title of the page using REACT.JS in ASP.NET.

I have tried importing DocumentTitle to set the title of the page.

import DocumentTitle from 'react-document-title';

App.JS -

class Hello extends React.Component {

```
componentDidMount() {
    document.title = "Home Page"
}
render() {
    return (
        <DocumentTitle title='Home'>
        <h1>
        Hello {this.props.name}  {this.props.time}
            </h1>
        </DocumentTitle>
    );
}
```

}

Index.cshtml

```
@using React.Web.Mvc

<h2>Index</h2>

<!-- React Component -->
<!-- Hello is react component-->
<!-- name is props -->
@Html.React("Hello", new
{
    name = "BC",
    time = DateTime.Now.Year,
    websiteTitle = ViewBag.message
})
```

I want the page title to be Set based on the ViewBag.message I have set in the controller. However, it is showing the default -